# Regression analysis between two variables?

Tags: statistics, regression

I just want to know if it is possible to study regression between two variables, knowing that one of the variables has stable values (always equal to 1) and which type of regression should I use?
This is my data, I intend to study the regression between Timeliness (the dependent variable) and Trustworthiness (the independent variable):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The regression coefficient will be zero.

A regression between two variables is just a correlation. To calculate a correlation between two (continous) variables by hand you
1.) demean both variables (subtract the mean of each variable from all values of this variable),
2.) multiply the demeaned values for x and y of each individual into a third column,
3.) take the sum of all these products,and lastly
4.) standardize (divide) by the pooled variance of both variables.

Demeaning the variable with just one type of value (step 1) will result in a variable consisting of only zero's, because each individuals value equals the mean. Multiplying anything by zero (step two) will remain zero, so your sum (step 3) will be a sum of many zeros. Lastly zero devided by any variance (step 4) remains zero.

Comment: I chose the example of continuous variables because it is most familiar to me, but all other approaches ( e.g. for ordinal or dichotomous variables) will come to the same result: A correlation quantifies how strongly two variables vary together. If one variable does not vary at all, it is also not varying together with the second variable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of user ajj is right , your `trustworthiness` is useless in this case, and you can just drop it, and rely on your `timeliness`variable.